# Watchers, Breakpoints, single-step and stepthrough

Tags: debugging, breakpoints

I know what a breakpoint is: it pauses the execution of code at certain points. I think its purpose is to check the value of certain variables at certain points in the program. However, watchers, single-step and stepthrough seem to be the same thing. Are they the same?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- **Breakpoints** allow you to stop at a specific point without needing to step through line-by-line to get there. The program execution will stop whenever it gets to a breakpoint, this will (generally) override the step logic - it will stop there even if you did a step.
- **Step** executes the program until it gets to the "next" line and stops there ("next" could mean various things, see below). This allows you to execute the program line-by-line without needing to set a breakpoint on every line and easily move between methods.

  - **Step over** steps to the following line in the same method or goes back to the line where this method was called from in the calling method if this method is returning.
  - **Step in** is like "step over", but also steps into whatever method appears on the current line (starting at the first line of that method).
  - **Step out** steps out of the current method, i.e. runs until it returns and stops at the line where this method was called from in the calling method.
- **Watch** allows you to easily see the value of variables or more complex expressions during debugging without needing to manually check them every time. It might also allow you to stop execution when the variable changes - something that can be very useful for bigger applications.

These things may not all exist in all debugging tools, there may be others and they may sometimes have slightly different names.

They all broadly serve the purpose "to debug", and you don't technically need all of them, but having access to all of them tends to make the debugging process a lot easier.

Comment: Ok, but what's the difference between single-step and stepthrough

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, these things can have different names. Those specific terms are not well-known (in my experience), but I assume Single-Step could either be a grouping term including all 3 steps I described in my answer (i.e. what I simply called Step in my answer), or it refers to Step Over (likely) or Step In. Stepthrough likely refers to Step In, but it could arguably also refer to Step Over. If this is regarding some course or class you're taking, the best idea would be to get the definitions directly from there. If it's about a debug tool, it's best to read the docs or test it.